# AHK - Read .txt from website?

Tags: autohotkey

So, I can make my AHK script read from an local file, but I'd like to make it read from an remote file. (on an website)

I could download the file locally and then read it but that's not what I want as I want to update the .txt from time to time without having to making the script re-download each time on start up.

So I've tried to do something like this:

```
FileRead, output, woop.txt
MsgBox, %output%
```

And boy, it worked fine! But like I said, that's for the local file. Now I tried to do the exact same with but with an link instead:

```
FileRead, output, http://mywebsite.net/woop.txt
MsgBox, %output%
```

(and yes, the file is on my site, just another domain)

However, it just returns null/nothing, so I'm curious how I'd go about doing this? I've tried to use Google etc, but haven't found an answer. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In the Autohotkey documentation, there is this:

```
UrlDownloadToFile, URL, Filename
```

It is supposed to download the file.  If it were a text file, you could download it and then read it.

If you want to see if you have an internet connection first, you could do this:

```
;example
If ConnectedToInternet()
   Msgbox, 64, WinInet.dll, ONLINE!
else
   Msgbox, 48, WinInet.dll, OFFLINE!
Return

ConnectedToInternet(flag=0x40) {
Return DllCall("Wininet.dll\InternetGetConnectedState", "Str", flag,"Int",0)
}
```

And I don't see any reason why the text file has to be in your domain.  In fact, you could download and read any file you wanted, so long as you could call it up in a browser.

Comment: Unfortunately, you by far can't `UrlDownloadToFile` anything that's accessible by your browser. Think of POST requests, login/cookies, User Agents, Authorization etc.

Comment: @MCL You are right to clarify that.  What I meant was that it could download any file that you have access to.  If authentication is necessary, obviously that would present another obstacle.  You should be able to download a file using that command, but it won't interact with the page for you.

Comment: Except for GET parameters ;)

Comment: You know, I like you, MCL.  Thanks for being on my team.

Comment: You too, sir! Especially since you seem to be immune to nitpicking.